# view default chosen k in mgcv's gam()

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

If using the default `k` in a smooth, e.g.

`gam(y ~ s(age), data=dat, family=binomial)`

how can I see which `k` was chosen ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2):

`k` isn't chosen; it has to be specified by the user. If the user doesn't specify `k` then a default value is used. For univariate smooths such as the one you fitted, the value is `k = 10`. Then one of the basis functions is removed due to identifiability constraints (it is confounded with the model intercept). Hence your smooth could use a maximum of 9 *effective degrees of freedom*.

If you do

```r
summary(model)
```

replacing `model` with your model object you'll see how many EDF are used by the smooth. Look at the `edf` column in the output.

If you want to know what value {mgcv} set `k` to, then you need to look at the help page for each type of smooth. The jumping off point is [`?smooth.terms`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.terms.html) and from there select the kind of smooth you are using, the default being a thin plate regression spline (TPRS), which is described at [`?tprs`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec.html). Not all smooths have an alias like this, so it is helpful to know that all smooths are described at help pages of the form `?smooth.construct.XXX.smooth.spec` with `XXX` being replaced by the character string you would pass to the `bs` argument.

Comment: thanks so much ! by "chosen" I just meant which `k` was used by default (I couldn't find it in the documentation). [This blog post](https://www.seascapemodels.org/rstats/2021/03/27/common-GAM-problems.html) plus your clarification that `k=10` by default helps me understand why I get errors when the number of levels of x is < 10.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've added something on where to find the defaults for smooths to the answer. The default for `k` depends on what type of smooth you are fitting. It's not `k = 10` for `s(x,z)` for example, and some smooths don't allow `k` to be set (it is just ignored).